# Uplodify returns HTTP Error 302 in firefox

Tags: php, firefox, file-upload, uploadify, jquery-file-upload

I am using [uplodify](http://www.uploadify.com) to upload files to my server.

It is working with no issue in Google Chrome. But when I try to upload a file using Firefox I get HTTP Error 302 and the file does not uploaded.

Here is my script

```
    <?php $timestamp = time();?>

        $('#file_upload').uploadify({
                'formData'     : {
                'timestamp' : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
                'token'     : '<?php echo md5($timestamp);?>',
                'session'   : '<?php echo $session->currentSessionID(); ?>',
                'upload_path': 'ticketing_center/',
                'allowed_extentions': 'jpg,jpeg,gif,PNG,JPG,png,JPEG,pdf,jpeg,zip,rar,doc,docx,csv,xls,xlsx,txt,csv,xml'
            },
            'auto' : true,
            'removeCompleted': true,
            'swf'      : '../../includes/uploadify.swf',
             'onError' : function(event, queueID, fileObj, errorObj) { alert(errorObj.type + ' ' + errorObj.info ); },
            'uploader' : '../../includes/uploadify.php',
            'fileSizeLimit' : '20MB',
            'fileTypeExts' : '*.gif; *.jpg; *.JPG; *.png; *.PNG; *.JPEG; *.pdf; *.jpeg; *.zip; *.rar; *.doc; *.docx; *.csv; *.xls; *.xlsx; *.txt; *.csv; *.xml;',
            'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) {

                if(response === true){
                    $('#attached_files').append('<input type="hidden" class="uploadedFiles" name="attachments[]" value="' + $.trim(data) + '" />');
                    $('#queue_final').append('<div style="display: block;" class="removeFile" id="' + $.trim(data) + '">(x)   ' + file.name + '</div>');
                } else {
                    alert('Invalid File Type');
                }

                $('.removeFile').click( function(){
                    var file_name = $(this).attr('id');

                    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog( "open" ).data('file_name', file_name);;

                }); 


            }

        });
```

I have done research prior posting this question but none of the solutions that I found solved my problem.

here is what I have tried so far
I have tried adding the session value to the script a `'session'   : '<?php echo $session->currentSessionID(); ?>'`

Then in my uploadify.php code I did

```
if (array_key_exists('session', $_REQUEST))
    session_id($_REQUEST['session']);
```

I tried adding `header( " HTTP/1.0 200 OK" );` to the top of my PHP script and that did not work as well.

I have tried to add the `onError` function to display any error but that is not displaying anything.

I am not sure what else could be causing this? Note that it is working on Chrome with no issues.

Here is a screenshot of the error after trying to upload
[image]

I am using Firefox 32.0.3. 
My Apache is running in Windows Server 2008 R2 I am not sure if this make a difference.

Comment: I just want to confirm the 302 error is not an HTTP 302 header... right?

Comment: it is HTTP Error 302. I just updated my question and added a screenshot

Comment: I would argue that an HTTP 302 "Found" header (commonly used for re-direction) is not really an error in the same way that a 4XX or 5XX series error might be. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302

Answer (score 0):

Flash will not pass through your existing PHP Session information, so if you are getting the 302 error it is likely that your application is returning the login URL to the Flash player. To resolve this issue, you could include the session information in scriptData and manage it manually in your application.

Comment: Can you please explain more on how to do this? if you look at my question, I tried to pass the session variable to but did not work. In fact, I removed the user authentication script from the uplodify.php and that still did not work